# URLRequest/URLLoader auto-converting POST request to GET

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, http

When I execute the following code:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://somehost/with/some/path?andsomequerystring=true");
urlRequest.method = 'POST';
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlRequest);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,  function(event:Event):void{
    trace('sweet');
});
```

It turns my explicit POST request to GET due to the presence of the querystring.  If I remove the querystring (and serialize as part of the POST body), it successfully makes the corresponding POST request.  Is there any way to prevent it from doing that?  My server requires that a POST request be made with a querystring.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out this library if nothing else gives: https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient it seems this gets past some of the issues I've run into using the provided classes.

Comment: Please, note about github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient. This is a custom socket library, thus it requires Socket Security Policy on the server you will be trying to fetch the data from. Not everybody provide this service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah think I found the answer, seems you have to specify a body as well or else it will still send as a GET request from their docs:

> Note: If running in Flash Player and the referenced form has no body,
>   Flash Player automatically uses a GET operation, even if the method is
>   set to URLRequestMethod.POST. For this reason, it is recommended to
>   always include a "dummy" body to ensure that the correct method is
>   used.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#url

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for - I will give this a try and get back to you

Comment: yep, this worked, thanks!  as an aside, the lesser-used mx.rpc.Operation class cannot be fed a POST body and still defaults to GET because of that technicality....lame

Comment: Awesome glad it worked out for you thanks for the extra info about Operation, I'm slowly sliding myself out of AS3 but I'll try to bury these tidbits in my brain for later use.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the way you are having your url. If you want to have your variables for POST method you need to use `URLVariables`.

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(YOUR_REQUEST_URL_HERE);
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.andsomequerystring = true;

urlRequest.data = variables;
urlRequest.method = 'POST';
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlRequest);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,  function(event:Event):void{
    trace('sweet');
});
```