# Flash as3 - API request with custom headers: POST but appears as GET (IOError #2032)

Tags: json, actionscript-3, error-handling

i have this file that makes an API request somewhere to retrieve JSON data.
The request needs to have 2 custom headers. I've read that custom headers require the request to be a POST.

I've read all the previous questions here and also on other sites, i think the code shows it pretty well... The "funny" part is that at some point i created a logger (environment: Tomcat) to see why it wasn't loading, and apparently the request i'm sending is a GET even if i've specified for it to be a POST...

Code

```
var url:String = "your_url_here";

var headers:Array = [
    new URLRequestHeader("user-id","your_user-id"),
    new URLRequestHeader("custom-auth","your_custom_auth_code"),
    new URLRequestHeader("Accept","application/json")
    ];

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.requestHeaders = headers;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.contentType = "application/json";
request.url = url;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT; 
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);

loader.load(request);

private function handleError(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
        sometextcontainer.txt01.text = e.toString();
        }

private function decodeJSON(e:Event) {
        var Info:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data);
        // text fillers
}
```

The error: #2032 **STREAM ERROR** but i was 100% sure about the URL being correct, so i made a logger to actually see what was happening on the other side and surprise surprise... The request appears to be a GET!

What did i do wrong? Ideas?

Note1: i don't have sandbox security problems as i already placed Global exceptions;

Note2: i tried the request in REST with the custom headers (as POST) and it works (and the logger says i actually made a POST...)

Thanks for your kind help! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774611/urlrequest-urlloader-auto-converting-post-request-to-get

Answer (score 1):

That made the trick.

I'm adding the code in order to make everyone understand it better and quicker. Basically, i added the following:

```
var datareq:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
datareq.dummyTest = "true";
request.data = datareq;`
```

So now it looks like:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var datareq:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
datareq.dummyTest = "true";
request.data = datareq;
request.requestHeaders = headers;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.contentType = "application/json";
request.url = url;
```

Thanks for the help.