# Can't call WebAPI with valid token in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, asp.net-web-api

I have an ActionScript3 game that needs to make calls to a Web api. I can successfully get a token. After getting the token, I make a call which requires authentication but I always get {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}.
I'm doing a GET.

I can call the same api using PostMan without any issues.
Here's the headers I'm adding.

```
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This has to do with how networking is implemented in Flash Player.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774611/urlrequest-urlloader-auto-converting-post-request-to-get for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that adding data must cause the headers to get submitted and then it works.

Adding the following line fixed it. Note that the value names don't matter.

```
urlRequest.data = new URLVariables("Needed=Value");
```